# C# Getting async list error

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

**SEE EDITED QUESTION BELOW**

I have following problem.

I receive notification event from component I cannot change call:

```
Subject.Save();
```

My code has an event handler to catch the notification event fired in the component. 
The event handler is registered properly.

The notification I receive carries the source of event and `SomeEventArgs` args.

`SomeEventArgs` provides me with the data containing an ID I need.  Something like

```
private void myEventHandler(object source, SomeEventArgs e)
{
   string path = e.getData().getPath();
   ...
   ...
   ShowDisplay();  //display shows a form with the path in a grid
}
```

When I save one Subject, I have one notification and from its `SomeEventArgs` I can get the 
path I need.  So that works fine.

The problem is when I want to save multiple subjects.  For each subject's Save(), `myEventHandler` will eventually be fired and I will get the path like above.

The problem is that I dont want to call `ShowDisplay()` for each individual subject but for all of them at once.  So, if I have 10 Subjects, I want to receive 10 paths first, then show them all
10 in a single form opened by ShowDisplay().  So, ShowDisplay cannot be called from `myEventHandler` since that event handles only notification for one single subject.

I thought to have a global list and fill it with paths from each notification but that introduces global variable, plus I don't know when the list is filled with all 10 paths. It does not seem to be an elegant idea.

**EDITED QUESTION**
I am calling an async method to get names of products like

```
List<string> productNames = GetProductNamesAsync();
```

My Async method is like:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetProductNamesAsync()
{
  return await Task.Run(() => subject.GetList());
}
```

This returns error
Cannot implicitely convert type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`

Comment: Some instance of a type in that library will fire the event.  You need to register an event handler with that instance.  It's unclear from your question how you would get hold of that instance.

Comment: What is the name of an `event` that it fires on `Save()`? Assuming, it is `Saved`, you need to do `myObject.Saved += handler_name_here`. Signature of event handler is impossible to mention here unless event details are known.

Comment: I updated my post.  Thanks

Comment: you need to update your code more than that.. where is `myObject` declared / initialized also if your knowledge of events is limited, then why are you wasting time here when you should be looking up `C# MSDN Events` do some reading for explanation and examples..

Comment: After researching bit I figured out other way to do what I need to do but I run into another issue.  I have modified my question to reflect the problem I face now.  Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: For your update `List<string> productNames = GetProductNamesAsync();` needs to be `List<string> productNames = await GetProductNamesAsync();`, however you really should not make asyncronous wrappers for sync functions. It is much better to just do `List<string> productNames = await Task.Run(() => GetProductNames());`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  I cannot mark your comment as an answer.   Can you write it as an answer so I can mark it.  Thanks,

Comment: @cd491415 - Please don't edit questions so completely. The comments no longer make sense with regard to the updated question. Either edit at the end or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<string> productNames = GetProductNamesAsync();` needs to be `List<string> productNames = await GetProductNamesAsync();`, however you really should not make asynchronous wrappers for sync functions. It is much better to just do `List<string> productNames = await Task.Run(() => GetProductNames());`